# Correct use of WPF view model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, viewmodel

I'm teaching myself WPF. My window has two combo boxes: one for *Categories* and one for *Subcategories*. When the category selection changes, I want the list of subcategories to update to just those that are in the selected category.

I've created a simple view class for both of the combo boxes. My `SubcategoryView` class' constructor takes a reference to my `CategoryView` class and attaches an event handler for when the category selection changes.

```
public class SubcategoryView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected CategoryView CategoryView;

    public SubcategoryView(CategoryView categoryView)
    {
        CategoryView = categoryView;
        CategoryView.PropertyChanged += CategoryView_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void CategoryView_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedItem")
        {
            _itemsSource = null;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TextValuePair> _itemsSource;
    public ObservableCollection<TextValuePair> ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (_itemsSource == null)
            {
                // Populate _itemsSource
            }
            return _itemsSource;
        }
    }
}
```

I assign my `DataContext`s like this.

```
cboCategory.DataContext = new CategoryView();
cboSubcategory.DataContext = new SubcategoryView(cboCategory.DataContext as CategoryView);
```

The problem is that selecting a new item in my category combo box does not cause the subcategories to repopulate (even though I confirmed my `PropertyChanged` handler is being called).

What is the correct way to cause the list to repopulate?

Also, I welcome any other comments about this approach. Instead of passing my `CategoryView` to the constructor, is it better to indicate this declaratively somehow in the XAML?

Comment: Did you have a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185366/mvvm-wpf-master-detail-comboboxes

Comment: The way I see it, you are doing it all wrong. See the link @SreeHarshaNellore gave. All you need is a single view (with 2 combobox) and single viewmodel.

Comment: I'd give each category a collection of subcategories SubCategories. x:Name the Category combo CategorySelector. Bind the other combo's ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.SubCategories, ElementName=CategorySelector}". And bob's your uncle.

Comment: @Jai I'll check out the link. But when you say i'm doing it all wrong, are you able to articulate what it is you feel is wrong and why it'seems an issue?

Comment: @Ed I'm not sure I understand how that would work. Are you able to clarify further?

Comment: How are you populating the category combo?

Comment: I do not currently have VS installed so I cannot comment a detailed solution.

Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919262/populate-wpf-listbox-based-on-selection-of-another-listbox

Correct use of a view model: It should be for handling data and non UI related things. In this case we are handling UI related things, so should we really be using a view model?

In the solution suggested, you simply have the subcategory list point to the main list's selected item. Only one list is needed with one custom class.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have a similar class for the category combo that does basically the same thing.

Comment: So you're binding (in XAML) an `ObservableCollection<SimilarClass>` to the category combo's ItemsSource? And that collection is a property of your viewmodel? If not, you should be doing that.

Comment: @JonathanWood Why don't you keep a single viewmodel for both comboboxes. Bind combobox2 itemssource to some `ObservableCollection` in view model. On combobox1 selection changed fill the `ObservableCollection`. Thats all you would need to do, in my opinion.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: You're saying combining everything into one view model? Yeah, that seems to be the consensus. Focused more on just getting things working first though.

Comment: Separating it is making this whole lot more complicated. I think you only need one View that hosts two ComboBox, then have one single ViewModel that exposes two properties of `ObservableCollection<YourClass1> YourProperty1` and `ObservableCollection<YourClass2> YourProperty2`. First ComboBox binds to `YourProperty1` and Second ComboBox binds to `YourProperty2`. For `YourProperty1`, attach a `CollectionChanged` event, and change `YourProperty2` with new instances in that event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how we do it in production code.

Each category knows what its subcategories are. If they're coming from a database or a disk file, the database/webservice method/file reader/whatever would return classes just like that, and you'd create the viewmodels to match. The viewmodel understands the structure of the information but knows and cares nothing about the actual content; somebody else is in charge of that.

Note that this is all very declarative: The only loop is the one that fakes up the demo objects. No event handlers, nothing in codebehind except creating the viewmodel and telling it to populate itself with fake data. In real life you do often end up writing event handlers for special cases (drag and drop, for example). There's nothing non-MVVMish about putting view-specific logic in the codebehind; that's what it's there for. But this case is much too trivial for that to be necessary. We have a number of `.xaml.cs` files that have sat in TFS for years on end exactly as the wizard created them.

The viewmodel properties are a lot of boilerplate. I have snippets ([steal them here](https://swissarmycrowbar.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/viewmodel-property-snippets-c6/)) to generate those, with the #regions and everything. Other people copy and paste.

Usually you'd put each viewmodel class in a separate file, but this is example code.

It's written for C#6. If you're on an earlier version we can change it to suit, let me know.

Finally, there are cases where it makes more sense to think in terms of having one combobox (or whatever) filtering another large collection of items, rather than navigating a tree. It can make very little sense to do that in this hierarchical format, particularly if the "category":"subcategory" relationship isn't one-to-many.

In that case, we'd have a collection of "categories" and a collection of *all* "subcategories", both as properties of the main viewmodel. We would then use the "category" selection to filter the "subcategory" collection, usually via a `CollectionViewSource`. But you could also give the viewmodel a private full list of all "subcategories" paired with a public `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` called something like `FilteredSubCategories`, which you'd bind to the second combobox. When the "category" selection changes, you repopulate `FilteredSubCategories` based on `SelectedCategory`.

The bottom line is to write viewmodels which reflect the semantics of your data, and then write views that let the user see what he needs to see and do what he needs to do. Viewmodels shouldn't be aware that views exist; they just expose information and commands. It's often handy to be able to write multiple views that display the same viewmodel in different ways or at different levels of detail, so think of the viewmodel as just neutrally exposing any information about itself that anybody might want to use. Usual factoring rules apply: Couple as loosely as possible (but no more loosely), etc.

ComboDemoViewModels.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ComboDemo.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
        #endregion INotifyPropertyChanged
    }

    public class ComboDemoViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        //  In practice this would probably have a public (or maybe protected) setter 
        //  that raised PropertyChanged just like the other properties below. 
        public ObservableCollection<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; } 
            = new ObservableCollection<CategoryViewModel>();

        #region SelectedCategory Property
        private CategoryViewModel _selectedCategory = default(CategoryViewModel);
        public CategoryViewModel SelectedCategory
        {
            get { return _selectedCategory; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedCategory)
                {
                    _selectedCategory = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion SelectedCategory Property

        public void Populate()
        {
            #region Fake Data
            foreach (var x in Enumerable.Range(0, 5))
            {
                var ctg = new ViewModels.CategoryViewModel($"Category {x}");

                Categories.Add(ctg);

                foreach (var y in Enumerable.Range(0, 5))
                {
                    ctg.SubCategories.Add(new ViewModels.SubCategoryViewModel($"Sub-Category {x}/{y}"));
                }
            }
            #endregion Fake Data
        }
    }

    public class CategoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public CategoryViewModel(String name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<SubCategoryViewModel> SubCategories { get; } 
            = new ObservableCollection<SubCategoryViewModel>();

        #region Name Property
        private String _name = default(String);
        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion Name Property

        //  You could put this on the main viewmodel instead if you wanted to, but this way, 
        //  when the user returns to a category, his last selection is still there. 
        #region SelectedSubCategory Property
        private SubCategoryViewModel _selectedSubCategory = default(SubCategoryViewModel);
        public SubCategoryViewModel SelectedSubCategory
        {
            get { return _selectedSubCategory; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _selectedSubCategory)
                {
                    _selectedSubCategory = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion SelectedSubCategory Property
    }

    public class SubCategoryViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public SubCategoryViewModel(String name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        #region Name Property
        private String _name = default(String);
        public String Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion Name Property
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window 
    x:Class="ComboDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboDemo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="4">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label>Categories</Label>
                <ComboBox 
                    x:Name="CategorySelector"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    MinWidth="200"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,4,4,4">
                <Label>Sub-Categories</Label>
                <ComboBox 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCategory.SubCategories}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory.SelectedSubCategory}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    MinWidth="200"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace ComboDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var vm = new ViewModels.ComboDemoViewModel();

            vm.Populate();

            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

## Extra Credit

Here's a different version of MainWindow.xaml, which demonstrates how you can show the same viewmodel in two different ways. Notice that when you select a category in one list, that updates `SelectedCategory` which is then reflected in the other list, and the same is true of `SelectedCategory.SelectedSubCategory`.

```
<Window 
    x:Class="ComboDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboDemo"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ComboDemo.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateExample" DataType="{x:Type vm:ComboDemoViewModel}">
            <ListBox
                ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
                >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CategoryViewModel}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                            <Label Width="120" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                            <ComboBox 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategories}"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubCategory}"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                MinWidth="120"
                                />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="4">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label>Categories</Label>
                <ComboBox 
                    x:Name="CategorySelector"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    MinWidth="200"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,4,4,4">
                <Label>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedCategory.Name, StringFormat='Sub-Categories in {0}:', FallbackValue='Sub-Categories:'}"/>
                </Label>
                <ComboBox 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCategory.SubCategories}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory.SelectedSubCategory}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                    MinWidth="200"
                    />
            </StackPanel>

            <GroupBox Header="Another View of the Same Thing" Margin="4">
                <!-- 
                Plain {Binding} just passes along the DataContext, so the 
                Content of this ContentControl will be the main viewmodel.
                -->
                <ContentControl
                    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateExample}"
                    Content="{Binding}"
                    />
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Unfortunately, I'm focused on another project at the moment but will go very carefully over everything you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

Using single view-model in that case is really simpler, as mentioned in comments. For example, I'll use just strings for combo box items.

To demonstrate correct using of view model, we'll track changes of *category* through binding rather than UI event. So, besides `ObservableCollection`s you'll need `SelectedCategory` property.

View-model:

```
public class CommonViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private string selectedCategory;

    public string SelectedCategory
    {
        get { return this.selectedCategory; }
        set
        {
            if (this.SetProperty(ref this.selectedCategory, value))
            {
                if (value.Equals("Category1"))
                {
                    this.SubCategories.Clear();
                    this.SubCategories.Add("Category1 Sub1");
                    this.SubCategories.Add("Category1 Sub2");
                }

                if (value.Equals("Category2"))
                {
                    this.SubCategories.Clear();
                    this.SubCategories.Add("Category2 Sub1");
                    this.SubCategories.Add("Category2 Sub2");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Categories { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string> { "Category1", "Category2" };

    public ObservableCollection<string> SubCategories { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}
```

Where `SetProperty` is implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

When you select *category*, the setter of `SelectedCategory` property triggers and you can fill *subcatagory* items depending on selected category value. **Do not replace collection object itself!** You should clear existing items and then add new ones.

In xaml, besides `ItemsSource` for both combo boxes, you'll need bind `SelectedItem` for *category* combo box.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Wrapper">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SubCategories}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then just assign view-model to wrapper's data context:

```
Wrapper.DataContext = new CommonViewModel();
```

And code for `BindableBase`:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett Can you eleborate?

Comment: I should back off from "it's not MVVM"; the Add thing you have is much better than adding ComboBoxItems in the codebehind. But it makes for simpler code if each category has a collection of its own subcategories and you bind to the selected category's subcategories property. You might also have one collection of all subcategories, and filter it with CollectionViewSource. .

Comment: @EdPlunkett Completely agree with you. This is why I added "For example, I'll use just strings..." - because OP just wanted simple things for the beginning :) I would also use `DelegateCommand` for tracking item changing in more complicated version (if track changes manually).